# I have an ajax call that works locally and on linux servers but does not on Azure even though the status is 200

Tags: php, ajax, azure, post

I have an ajax call that works locally and on linux servers but does not on Azure even though the status is 200 in all environments, including Azure. The directory that the has the PHP in it is in a virtual directory on Azure. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I have been digging my hair out on this for a while

The ajax call is below:

```
var form_data = new Object();
    form_data.RegYear = RegYear;
    form_data.LMSCID = LMSCID;
    form_data.ParentClubPermID = ParentClubPermID;

    $.ajax({
       url:'/ajax/reg/club/getclubsinyear.php',
       type:'POST',
       data:form_data,
       dataType:'html',
       success:function(return_data){   
            $('#ParentClubContainer').html(return_data);
            $('#ParentClubContainer').show();
            $('#ParentClubLoadingImage').hide();

            if (FirstTimeSelectingLMSC) {
                $('#WOGroupRecordForm select[name="ParentClubPermID"]').addClass('highlight_select');
            }
       },
       error:function(w,t,f){
            $('#ParentClubContainer').html('<div class="error_message">Error: Trouble displaying club information.</div>');
            $('#ParentClubContainer').show();
            $('#ParentClubLoadingImage').hide();
       }
    });
```

The PHP file that receives this data and displays the different clubs, in a select menu, based on the RegYear and LMSCID(the group's ID), from the form data, is below:

```
if (($LMSCID = $_POST['LMSCID']) && ($regYear = $_POST['RegYear']))
{
    if ($pdoLink = \Database::GetInstance()->GetPDO())
    {
        $sql = "SELECT
                    ClubRegistration.ClubPermID,
                    ClubRegistration.ClubName,
                    ClubRegistration.ClubAbbr
                FROM
                    ClubRegistration
                WHERE
                    ClubRegistration.Year = :regYear
                    AND
                    ClubRegistration.LMSCID = :LMSCID
                    AND
                    ClubRegistration.AllowWOGroups = '1'
                ORDER BY
                    ClubRegistration.ClubName ASC";
        if ($query = $pdoLink->prepare($sql))
        {
            $bindValues = array();
            $bindValues[":regYear"] = $regYear;
            $bindValues[":LMSCID"] = $LMSCID;

            if ($query->execute($bindValues))
            {
                if ($query->rowCount())
                {
                    $return = "<select name=\"ParentClubPermID\">
                                    <option value=\"\"> </option>";
                    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $return .= "<option value=\"" . $row['ClubPermID'] . "\"";
                        if ($row['ClubPermID'] == $_POST['ParentClubPermID'])
                        {
                            $return .= " selected=\"selected\"";    
                        }
                        $return .= ">" . $row['ClubName'] . " (" . $row['ClubAbbr'] . ")</option>";
                    }
                    $return .= "</select>";
                    echo $return;
                    exit;
                }
                else
                {
                    $return = "";
                    $return .= "<strong>No clubs found using your search criteria.</strong>";
                    echo $return;
                    exit;   
                }
            }
        }                           
    }
}
echo "<strong>Something went wrong getting club information.</strong>";
exit;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you get any error messages when you make an ajax call to the PHP?

Comment: No errors and the status is 200, which means successful

Comment: Is there any other response output?

Comment: It shows form data in console and all the variables are populated

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're asking. Can you please edit your question to include the result you're getting and what you're expecting?

Comment: I added a screen shot of the status 200 and the form data being sent

Comment: I added crossDomain: true and it now works

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved. I added crossDomain: true and it now works.